# Does time exist in a universe with no movement?

Tags: spacetime, time

If everything just stays in place, is it meaningful to say that everything stays in place as time passes? Or does time not exist at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neglecting specifics, your question is equivalent to asking whether height exists in a two-dimensional world. A 3D world with z-translation symmetry acts very much like a 2D world, just like a (3+1)D world invariant under temporal evolution acts very much like a "frozen" 3D world.

It's hard to say whether time "exists". Certainly, in such a world, the fourth number of "time" is a completely unnecessary number to describe locations/events. The world is a three-dimensional manifold; regions of it can locally be described just with three numbers. If it's flat space, that coordinate system of three numbers trivially applies to all space.